# Error when passing parameters into a function within a UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to pass a parameter (coordinates) into an override of the drawRect function. I'm not exactly sure why the parameters aren't being passed to the function

```
class Draw2D: UIView {
var startCord: CGPoint?
init(startCord: CGPoint) {
    self.startCord = startCord
    super.init(frame: CGRect())
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let locations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

    let colors = [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]

    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace,
        colors, locations)


    var endPoint = CGPoint()

    endPoint.x = 200
    endPoint.y = 200
    let startRadius: CGFloat = 0
    let endRadius: CGFloat = 75

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient (context, gradient, startCord!,
        startRadius, endPoint, endRadius,
        0)



    }
```

}

Here's the paramaters I passed through the button action

```
@IBAction func skittle(sender: AnyObject) {


    let plsWork = Draw2D(startCord: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

This code normally plots a circle in the UIView, but I'm trying to have it plot only when a UI button is pressed. How can I pass parameters from the ViewController.swift into this separate Draw2D.swift?

Comment: As far as I can see, the code you've provided does not have any optional values. Could you post a little more content from you error message?

Comment: I am not sure, but, if you use var plsWork instead of let plsWork?

Comment: Sure, ezCoding this also shows up   CGContextDrawRadialGradient (context, gradient, startCord!,startRadius, endPoint, endRadius,0) >>>>>>>>>
  Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

Comment: Nekak, I tried that but no luck, same error

Comment: That doesn't help sorry. At some point the error message tells you, which function call leads to the error.

Comment: OK. I've spotted something. Why is `startCord` marked as `Optional`, if you initialize it in the init?

Comment: When draw gradient you use "startCord!" I think you should use "self.startCord!"

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses ezCoding! If `startCord` isn't marked as `optional`, `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` has error `Property 'self.startCord' not initialized at super.init call`. What does that error signify?